# Doing bean inject in camel test

Tags: apache-camel

I have a camel app which look something like below which has a route like below:-

from("direct:getMarketplaceOrders").to("bean:orderHelper?method=getMarketplaceOrders");

The entry point of the code look something like below:

```
public class OrderMainApp {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    OrderMainApp orderMainApp = new OrderMainApp();
    DefaultCamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    ProducerTemplate producer = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
    camelContext.setRegistry(orderMainApp.createRegistry(producer));
    camelContext.addRoutes(new OrderRouteBuilder(producer));
    camelContext.start();
    }

    protected JndiRegistry createRegistry(ProducerTemplate producer) throws Exception {
    JndiRegistry jndi = new JndiRegistry();
    OrderHelper orderHelper = new OrderHelper();
    orderHelper.setProducer(producer);
    jndi.bind("orderHelper", orderHelper);
    return jndi;
    }
}
```

In `OrderRouteBuilder` `configure` has routes like below:-

```
//processor is a custom JSONProcessor extending Processor
from("jetty:http://localhost:8888/orchestratorservice").process(processor);
from("direct:getMarketplaceOrders").to("bean:orderHelper?method=getMarketplaceOrders");
```

My goal is to test the response I receive from `bean:orderHelper?method=getMarketplaceOrders` when I place a request on `direct:getMarketplaceOrders`

orderHelper.getMarketplaceOrders looks like below:-

`public OrderResponse getMarketplaceOrders(GetMarketplaceOrdersRequest requestParam) throws Exception`

My test class look something like below:-

```
public class OrderMainAppTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Produce(uri = "direct:getMarketplaceOrders")
    protected ProducerTemplate template;

    @EndpointInject(uri = "bean:orderHelper?method=getMarketplaceOrders")
    protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

    @Test
    public void testSendMatchingMessage() throws Exception {
    String expectedBody = "<matched/>";

    template.sendBody("{\"fromDateTime\": \"2016-01-11 10:12:13\"}");

    resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(expectedBody);

    resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
        from("direct:getMarketplaceOrders").to("bean:orderHelper?method=getMarketplaceOrders");
        }
    };
    }
}
```

Whenever I am running the test I am getting the below exception:-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type: org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint which cannot be injected via @EndpointInject/@Produce for: Endpoint[bean://orderHelper?method=getMarketplaceOrders]
```

I am guessing this is because I am not able to pass on OrderHelper to the camel test context. Can some one let me know how can I inject the bean in the mock result end point?

**EDIT:-**

I tried modifying my test class as follows:-

```
    public class OrderMainAppTest extends CamelTestSupport {

        protected OrderHelper orderHelper = new OrderHelper();

        @Produce(uri = "direct:getMarketplaceOrders")
        protected ProducerTemplate template;

        @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:intercepted")
        MockEndpoint mockEndpoint;


        @Before
        public void preSetup() throws Exception {
        orderHelper.setProducer(template);
        };

        @Test
        public void testSendMatchingMessage() throws Exception {

        GetMarketplaceOrdersRequest request = new GetMarketplaceOrdersRequest();
        request.setFromDateTime("2016-01-11 10:12:13");
        request.setApikey("secret_key");
        request.setMethod("getMarketplaceOrders");
        request.setLimit(10);
        request.setOffset(2);

        template.sendBody(request);
        mockEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived("{\"success\":\"false\"");
        }

        @Override
        protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
interceptSendToEndpoint("bean:orderHelper?method=getMarketplaceOrders")
        .to("mock:intercepted");            from("direct:getMarketplaceOrders").to("bean:orderHelper?method=getMarketplaceOrders");
            }
        };
        }

        @Override
        protected JndiRegistry createRegistry() throws Exception {
        return getRegistry();
        }

        protected JndiRegistry getRegistry() {
        JndiRegistry jndi = new JndiRegistry();
        jndi.bind("orderHelper", orderHelper);
        return jndi;
        }
    }
```

The above code is making the request correctly and is flowing through my app correctly. But I am not able to intercept the response of `orderHelper.getMarketplaceOrders`. The above code is intercepting only the request. I tried changing to `template.requestBody(request)`. But still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By updating my `createRouteBuilder` as shown below. I am able to intercept the response and send it to a mock endpoint where I can do the assertion.

```
@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
return new RouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
    from("direct:getMarketplaceOrders").to("bean:orderHelper?method=getMarketplaceOrders").onCompletion()
        .to("mock:intercepted");
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means you can't inject a `bean:` endpoint into a `MockEndpoint`.

If you want to "intercept" the call into your `OrderHelper`, you can use `interceptSendToEndpoint` in your route :

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:intercepted")
MockEndpoint mockEndpoint;

...

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
  return new RouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() {

      interceptSendToEndpoint("bean:orderHelper?method=getMarketplaceOrders")
        .to("mock:intercepted");

      from("direct:getMarketplaceOrders")
        .to("bean:orderHelper?method=getMarketplaceOrders");
  }
};
```

See : http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html

Comment: I don't understand: you never instantiate in your test `OrderMainApp`, how are you "testing it" ? I was explaining to you what is the error you see, and how to fix it: this error has nothing to do with the registry, it happens before. Anyway, you can't test `OrderMainApp.createRegistry` because you need a camelcontext to create a registry, and in `CamelTestSupport` you need a registry to create a camelcontext.

Comment: the answer I gave you is the same. Add to your route builder an `interceptSendToEndpoint` as in my example

Comment: if I add this in my route builder `interceptSendToEndpoint("bean:orderHelper?method=getMarketplaceOrders").to("mock:intercepted");` I am only able to intercept the incoming request. Actually I need the response of `orderHelper.getMarketPlaceOrders` so that I can assert on the ouput. So is there a way I can intercept only the response/outgoing messages?

Comment: use `requestBody` instead of `sendBody` : you'll get the response

Comment: If I get you correctly I just did `template.requestBody(request);`
 But still I am getting the request only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105362/discussion-between-tuk-and-jeremie-b).